# Contractor asking for private keys to develop push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, digital-certificate

A contractor is asking for a private key and suggesting creating a new push certificate for this app with a new certificate signing request. Then to share the certificate and private keys with them.

I wondering how we can use these contractors without giving them private keys?

I am not sure how to manage this workflow. Any thoughts on how to manage would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificates and keys used for the server side push service (interacting with Apple's APNS server) are different from the certificates and keys use to sign the app. If it's only for that your fine. You'll set this up when enabling push services on the app ID in the developer portal. You will however need to re-create your provisioning profiles in order to compile the app to receive the push messages.

If your contractor has their own dev account you might want to consider adding them as a team member so they can set up their own dev certificates.